# Combining line vector shapefiles with different attributes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, line, overlay

I'm using ArcGIS 10.3 for desktop.

I have two shapefiles, both with polyline vector data for roads in the same area. This area is quite large, approximately 7,500 km², so there are a lot of roads in both files. One of the datasets contains condition rating information for the roads, the other has the width of the roads. It is necessary for me to combine these two files together so as to have the attributes in the same shapefile to work on.

The width dataset contains more roads and is better in terms of connectivity than the condition dataset. I have tried creating a buffer around the condition data then using the Identity tool to combine that data with the width data that overlays it. However this creates a lot of slivers of road at junctions that need to be corrected manually. While this is okay for a small area it is unworkable if I scale up to the whole county area. Is there a way of fixing this? Or is there a better way to combine the line datasets?

Comment: Make sure width lines have unique ID. Derive condition lines midpoints.   Spatially join them 1:1 to Closest width lines. Transfer conditions info to width table using attribute join with unique ID.

Comment: This may be feasible. So am I spatially joining them without bringing over the attributes of the condition data? When I do this I still have a dataset with the same geometry and attributes as the original width dataset. Could you expand on this a little please?